# Scrollbar appearing when trying to overlay a circular div with a background image on top of another div

Tags: html, css, web

I would like to overlay a circular div on top of another for the effect shown here: 
[image: Desired shot]

I have been able to get this look achieved through the code below, however, you are able to scroll inside the circular div which moves the image like this:

[image: Scrollbar appears]

My goal is to eliminate the scrollbar from appearing.

Here is the HTML and CSS I am using:
https://jsfiddle.net/nLk7gqjd/

HTML

```
<div id="main-picture">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/img_girl.jpg">
</div>
<div id="other-box">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#other-box {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: black 2px solid;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2.5%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

#main-picture {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: overlay;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
#main-picture img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I assume you still want the circle around the image to appear over the rectangle, if that's true then overflow: hidden will not work. I would suggest displaying the divs absolutely and using [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Comment: That helped! I updated the fiddle and left a working version as the answer to this question

Comment: Your question indicated you wanted to get rid of the scroll bar, not also have the border circle over the square. I answered that and got downvoted. Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Froy T was correct in suggesting to use position absolute. I was able to achieve the desired effect with it as shown below:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lr7utvoa/

```
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent scrolling on an element, add:

```
#main-picture {
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: If you I do that, it doesn't achieve the effect I'm looking for since I am using overflow: overlay

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, overlay isn't doing anything for you. Overlay is a value only supported by webkit browsers and it mimics auto. When I change it to hidden, the affect appears the same to me. What appears different for you between those two overflow settings?

Answer (score 0):

```
#main-picture {
   overflow: none;
}
```

This will do...